# How to return two values from a method

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, return

I want to get two strings from a method called but the calculation inside that takes few seconds so i have no idea to return both values and assign them  to a List or two Strings after the calculation

This is how i called the method -

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    var calc = new Calculation().resultCalculation(dateOfBirth: dob, timeOfBirth: tob, gender: genderId, city: cities);
    results = calc;
    print(results);
    print(results[0]);
    super.initState();
  }
```

And this is how i returned the values -

```
    return [bornDay, bornCity];
```

If someone can give me a better way to call this method and return both values 
it would be great :)

Method that takes time -

```
cityCalculate() async {
  DateTime earlyTime;
  DateTime lateTime;
  String city;

  QuerySnapshot snaps =
      await Firestore.instance.collection('cities').getDocuments();
  for (var docs in snaps.documents) {
    earlyTime = DateTime.parse(docs['beforeTime']);
    lateTime = DateTime.parse(docs['afterTime']);
    city = docs['city'];
    if (birthDayTime.isAfter(earlyTime) && birthDayTime.isBefore(lateTime)) {
      bornCity = city;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can do that is to use a `Map` or a `List` (as you've done).

1. Using Map `return {"bornDay": bornDay, "bornCity" bornCity"}`
2. Using List (as you've done) `return [bornDay, bornCity]`

Call the function like this

```
@override
  void initState() async{
    var calc = await Calculation().resultCalculation(dateOfBirth: dob, timeOfBirth: tob, gender: genderId, city: cities);
    results = calc;
    print(results);
    print(results[0]);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Yeah but it shows an error - "type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>"

Comment: if your function has an async modifier then you should use add await before calling it.
    var calc =  await Calculation().resultCalculation();

Comment: Yes it worked 
But the problem is still it shows null because the calculation of the returning value takes time
So it return a null value

Comment: Then post you calculation method please, something is probable wrong with it

Comment: I added the part of the method that takes time to the Question
It's because of firebase integration

Comment: there is no `return` in your method that's why you're getting null

Comment: I solved the issue by using a FutureBuilder
Thanks for your support :)